# Why can't I fuse moths?

Tags: flutter-starlight

I have two of the same moth but I don't have the option to fuse them, why? There isn't anything I can do, and it doesn't tell me why I can't fuse them. I've tried restarting it but nothing. Please help!

Comment: Is one max level? If they're max level you can't fuse any further.

Comment: No, it says I have to fuse them to continue leveling up.

Answer (score -1):

Anon is your Moth Level 4 that's when it's maxed level. Also there should be Like a tiny moth above your regular moths head and if the body and the four wings are yellow that means it can no longer be fused. If this is not the case I would go on facebook and look up Flutter starlight and complain on there.